# When should I Init my tiles in my Android view?

Tags: java, android

The dimnensions of my tiles depend of the width annd height of the screen.

When should I give them their dimensions?

If I init them in OnSizeChanged, then I'll need a boolean to know if it's the first time onSizeChanged occured.

Would it be more appropriate to store my tile dimensions in relative values?

What would be the proper way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I do this, I use a `GlobalLayoutListener`, something like this:

```
final ViewGroup myViewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.my_viewgroup);
ViewTreeObserver vto = myViewGroup.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        //myViewGroup should now have dimensions, but sometimes
        //it takes two passes, so...
        if(myViewGroup.getWidth() == 0) return;

        //Set whatever stuff here
        myTileSizes = whateverSize;

        //Remove this listener -- no longer needed
        myViewGroup.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
}
```

Personally, I like your idea of just keeping a boolean for whether or not you've done the measurements. Should be just as effective.